# Sending a laptop's function keys in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I have trouble using my laptop's [Fn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fn_key) key + [function keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_key#MS-DOS/Windows) (F1-F12), because they're all lined up without any space between them, and it’s not a shortcut; it’s time waste... It's [HP ProBook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_ProBook) 4540s, and you'd understand if you used this...

So, I googled and found [AutoHotKey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) (AHK).

Now I want to send:

```
Fn + F8 (volume down) and
Fn + F9 (volume up) as another shortcut, i.e.,
Fn + NumpadSub and
Fn + NumpadAdd
```

The following is what I tried so far,

```
; Volume Down
126NumpadSub::
Send {vkFFsc126 down}
Send {F8}
Send {vkFFsc126 up}
return
```

126 is the scan code for my Fn key.
But it does not work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you receiving an error? `126NumpadSub` is not a valid key I would assume.

Comment: Yes sir, it says **Invalid Hotkey**. I also tried SC126NumpadSub but it didn't work, but it also encountered no error, and **NumpadSubSC126** would encounter Invalid Hotkey Error

Comment: It is unclear if it is the [Fn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fn_key) key or the [function keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_key#MS-DOS/Windows) F1 through F12. "Fn" points to, well, "Fn" (if it is literal) and using plural points to the 12 function keys.

Comment: OK, `Fn+F9` points to the single `Fn` key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the shortcut <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>NumpadSub</kbd>, you would map them like so:

```
SC126 & NumpadSub::
    Send {SC126 down}
    Send {F8}
    Send {SC126 up}
Return
```

Here is the [Keys List](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm) to use for future reference.

Comment: This has been tagged as correct, but your comment states otherwise, please update comment to make it clear for other readers if this solved your question. Here is a related question that answer the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423724/finding-the-scan-code-of-fn-key