# What is the key scan code of the Fn key for use in AutoHotkey (AHK)?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to emulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, and so far this is my code:

```
 #InstallKeybdHook
 #Persistent

  SC126 & s::
     Send ^{s}
  return
```

My problem is that I don't know the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key's scan code.
How can I find it?

Comment: [Here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys)'s how you can find scan codes for special keys.

Comment: Check out this [link](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/27841-remapping-the-fn-key-a-solution/)

Comment: @Karthik Sampath 
the link you gave is for pressing specific "Key" to emulate "Fn + Another Key", while my question is how to use this "Fn + Another Key" to emulate specific "key". but anyway thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: @MCL thanks man, i've tried that , but it's not working,

Comment: Related (also about the "Fn" key and AutoHotkey): *[Sending a laptop's function keys in AutoHotKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491754)*

Comment: The key scan codes for the 'Fn' key itself (unlike other modifier keys) may not even be available on the signal level (at least not in PS/2 mode). Are they trapped by the keyboard itself? And is some synthesised key scan code send out on  the physical copper wire (or RF/wireless)? Isn't there a canonical Stack Overflow question for this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `Fn` key does not have a scan code.

The keyboard driver does not expose the `Fn` key to the operating system, so basically your operating system (and therefore AutoHotkey) does not know that it exists.

When you press the `Fn` key in combination with a supported key, the keyboard driver reports a single key press to the operating system with a different scan code. Basically, it tells the operating system that a different key was pressed.

Comment: @Persona93 look at this page , that's what makes me question this, i wish i know how to know the scan code, i just need the scan code, that's all.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491754/sending-laptop-function-key-autohotkey?lq=1

Comment: It seems that the person who posted that never got it working. They probably misunderstood what the scan key was for. I would suggest using the left windows key for hotkeys. It's right next to to Fn key and a quick Google search will tell you what the built in Windows key hotkeys are so you can avoid overriding them if you want to.

Comment: My mba 5,2 lists this under `evtest`:
`Event: time 1644010787.861254, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 464 (KEY_FN), value 1
Event: time 1644010787.861254, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1644010787.957190, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 464 (KEY_FN), value 0
Event: time 1644010787.957190, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------`  So it does have a code when pressed alone, just not under X11.

Answer (score 9):

When you press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key in combination with a supported key, the keyboard driver reports the presses to the operating system (Windows in this case).

You can find the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key scan code by:

1. Go to the tray icon
2. Right-click *Script*
3. Click *Open*
4. Click *View* and then *Key History* and *Script Info* (alternatively <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>)
5. Once you press the key, you can refresh (<kbd>F5</kbd>) and scroll to the bottom to see the codes

[image: See the attached screenshot Fn key]

Comment: After you right click autohotkey icon you have to choose edit script, then add these lines: `#Persistent
#InstallMouseHook

#InstallKeybdHook

while !(getKeyState("F1", "T"))

      KeyHistory

return

esc::exitapp`
and choose reload script. Copy it from [here](http://superuser.com/a/1055167/137871) because it needs new line feeds which I can't enter in comments. To disable the history you can simply add `#KeyHistory 0`.

Comment: The "tray" icon refers to the system tray.  Similar instructions [here](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/15037-noob-get-scancode-of-pressed-key/), for redundancy in case anyone has trouble following the above.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use a Mac keyboard and would like to map the Fn key to Insert (and also get other standard Windows keys, like PrintScreen), then you might want to try the 'hidfalum' driver.  It's available here: http://www.bimoid.com/download/utils/hidfalum.zip

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Using a Mac keyboard with Windows?